# Laravel :auth cannot login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to implement authentication functionally in laravel

This is my post login  function

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password' => $request->get('password')])){
        return redirect()->route('index');}
else{
        return 'not entered ';
    }
}
```

However, I receive `not entered` each time.

My passwords stored as **plain-text** in database (Not hashed).

Comment: Can you please post the full code in this function ?

Comment: i edited full funtion on question

Comment: Why don't you simply use guard instead. Over here did you imported `Auth` and what error are you getting over here. Try simply using `Auth::attempt($request->only('email','password'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know that , when you're using `Auth::attempt()` , and passing password init , laravel will hash the password for you .. for example you have a 123456 password in your table . then you're trying to login with `Auth::attempt()` .. your input password will be changed into "kjdfklsjgkjfglkjdgkjdfg" this .. Now you realize ? why you method is returning 'not entered ' instead of redirecting to admin route

Try to write a seed where you have to use Hash facade `Hash::make($password)` or global function `bcrypt($password)` , the you'll get a hashed passoword in your database . after that you'll be able to use Auth::attempt() with a success

and it's better to use $request->input() , you know it looks good! :)

try using $request->input() instead of $request->get()

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){

  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])){
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    }else{
        return 'not entered ';
    }
}
```

happy coding!

Comment: I think the problem with a wrong password :) , not with the code! . in your database is the password is hashed ?

Comment: no it is not hashed . this is how  it looks on db , **aaa@hhh**  ,**asd**

Comment: Now! i get it! :D , bro .. do you know that , when you're using Auth::attempt() , and passing password init , laravel will hash the password for you .. 

for example you have a 123456 password in your table . then you're trying to login with Auth::attempt() .. your input password will be changed into "kjdfklsjgkjfglkjdgkjdfg"  this .. Now you realize ? why you method is returning 'not entered ' instead of redirecting to admin route?

Comment: ok i got it now , thank you very much , but i  can fix this ?

Comment: added some extra info in the answer , try to follow that .. remember the password in the database have to be hashed! get it? @AliYiğit

Comment: ```Hash::make()``` or ```bcrypt()```

Comment: You deserve a cookie bro!